# RCurl, error: connection time out

Tags: r, rcurl

I use the XML and RCurl packages of R to get data from a website.
The script needs to scrap 6,000,000 pages, so I created a loop.

```
for (page in c(1:6000000)){

 my_url = paste('http://webpage.....')
 page1 <- getURL(my_url, encoding="UTF-8")
 mydata <- htmlParse(page1, asText=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
 title <- xpathSApply(mydata, '//head/title', xmlValue, simplify = TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")

.....
.....
.....}
```

However, after a few loops I get the error message:

> Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding)
>   :    connection time out

The problem is that I don't understand how the "time out" works. Sometimes the process ends after 700 pages while other times after 1000, 1200 etc pages. The step is not stable. 
When the connection is timed out, I can't access this webpage from my laptop, for 15 minutes.
I thought of using a command to delay the process for 15 minutes every 1000 pages scrapped

```
if(page==1000) Sys.sleep(901)
```

, but nothing changed.

Any ideas what is going wrong and how to overcome this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RCurl, error: couldn't connect to host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620123/rcurl-error-couldnt-connect-to-host)

Comment: I think you'll need to handle HTTP errors if you are going to make it through 6M pages.  Also, you say "a website" - if you are hitting the same site, I'd bet some sort of adaptive firewall is kicking in and temporarily blocking you. (You are respecting robots.txt, right?)

Comment: I solved it. Just added Sys.sleep(1) to each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Just added `Sys.sleep(1)` to each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a call in R to a native installation of `curl` using the command `System()`. This way, you get access to all the `curl` options not currently supported by `RCurl` such as `--retry <num>`. The option `--retry <num>` will cause an issued `curl` query to repeatedly try again at ever greater lengths of time after each failure, i.e. retry 1 second after first failure, 2 seconds after second failure, 4 seconds after third failure, and so on. Other time control options are also available at the cURL site http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html.