# RCurl, error: couldn't connect to host

Tags: r, rcurl

I use Rstudio server, and the packages RCurl and XML. I tried to scrape a webpage, but after having done it once successfully, I got the error  message:

```
 Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
 couldn't connect to host
```

when trying to get the URL:

```
getURL(my_url, encoding="UTF-8", followLocation = TRUE)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What web-page are you trying to scape? How many calls are you doing?

Comment: Have you tried it locally (assuming the server is running at a different location)?

Comment: I am doing something simiar and having the same error. I can get the url manually opening hte browser. Were you able to solve your poblem and how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try setting your RCurlOptions:

```
options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "my.proxy", proxyport = my.proxyport.number))
```

I hope it helps.